# Cisco AnyConnect fails on El Capitan - Unable to locate host scan library

Tags: network, vpn

I am facing below error on my MacBook which runs on El Capitan, when I try to connect to VPN it says Posture Assessment failed: unable to locate hostscan library.

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure your proxy/VPN addresses are correct?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS 10.11 requires Cisco AnyConnect 3.1.100 or later.